# Why is this session not being set?

Tags: php, function, session

just trying to do something somewhat simple with sessions.

Im just starting to expand my website so have started using a functions file included on every page.

Im am trying to make a page only accesable if you are logged in, if not it redirects you and then sets a session. This session is this detected and a 'log in' message is displayed.

I have had this code working before, but isnt working since i have messed around with things.

So on the page that needs a check for the logged in user, this is right at the top of the page:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require 'functions/core-functions.php';
isUserLoggedIn_referLogin();
?>
```

This is the function:

```
// User Logged In Check For Protected Pages - Promt Login

function isUserLoggedIn_referLogin() {

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $_SESSION['needlogin'] = "1";
    header('location: ' .$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}

}
```

And this is used to show the erorr:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['needlogin'])) {
    echo '
    <div class="invalidlogin">Please login to use this feature.</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['needlogin']);
}
```

I have checked on firebug but its showing that no session is being set.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this all the code that is used? You may have an issue with where you start your `session_start()`.

Comment: its all the code that affects this feature im trying to add. Can you expand where the issue of the session_start() may lay?

Comment: Are you outputting anything to the browser before calling `session_start()`?

Comment: nope, its always at the very top :/

Comment: Then you'll need to provide all the code that is used to generate these pages as this is the easiest way to figure out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call session_write_close

Answer (score 0):

If Gavin's answer does not solve your problem make sure `session_start()` is called before anything is sent to the browser. Here's an except from http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before
>   outputing anything to the browser.